# Docker: Не удается получить доступ к сайту

Tags: docker

Пытаюсь настроить простейший сайт в докере для теста.

Система windows 7, поэтому ставил Docker Toolbox под VirtualBox.
Клонирую готовый образ из реестра, все работает.

Настраиваю по этой статье https://totaku.ru/ustanovka-lemp-s-pomoshchiu-dockera/, все вроде устанавливается, даже phpMyAdmin запускается. А сам сайт - нет.

В браузере указываю http://192.168.99.100:8000

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        curl \
        wget \
        git \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng-dev \
    && pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1 \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mbstring mysqli pdo_mysql zip \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-enable mcrypt

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

ADD php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/40-custom.ini

WORKDIR /var/www

CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "8000:80"
        volumes:
            - ./hosts:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - ./www:/var/www
            - ./logs:/var/log/nginx
        links:
            - php
    php:
        build: ./images/php
        links:
            - mysql
        volumes:
            - ./www:/var/www
    mysql:
        image: mariadb
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
            - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
    pma:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        restart: always
        links:
            - mysql:mysql
        ports:
            - 8183:80
        environment:
            PMA_HOST: mysql
            MYSQL_USERNAME: root
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
```

hello-test.conf:

```
server {
    index index.php;
    server_name hello.test;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/hello.test;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

Куда копать? Подскажите.

---

В комментариях не помещается, пишу здесь.

Вот что выдает docker ps:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
e66df5aa188e        nginx:latest            "nginx -g 'daemon of"   About a minute ago   Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp     dockerproject_nginx_1
195a7bd78f34        phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin   "/docker-entrypoint."   About a minute ago   Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:8183->80/tcp     dockerproject_pma_1
65ac81c649f5        dockerproject_php       "docker-php-entrypoi"   About a minute ago   Up 2 minutes        9000/tcp                 dockerproject_php_1
2a6fb979dd6a        mariadb                 "docker-entrypoint.s"   About a minute ago   Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp   dockerproject_mysql_1
```

dockerproject_php_1 прописал в dockerproject_php_1 hello-test.conf

Не повлияло не на что.

Пытаюсь вывести логи командой docker logs e66df5aa188e, не выводит ничего.

Comment: Скоре всего у вас отваливается контейнер с веб сервером. Запустите docker-compose up  без ключа -d и посмотрите в логах, почему у вас отваливается контейнер .

Comment: либо `docker logs <container id>`

Comment: В конце логов пишет:

pma_1    | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.22.0.4. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this messa
ge
pma_1    | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.22.0.4. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this messa
ge
pma_1    | [Thu Feb 13 15:19:04.457700 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) PHP/7.4.1 configured -- resuming normal operations

Тут нее так что-то?

Comment: не в конце лога смотрите. а смотрите лог nnginx , вот уважаемый @tCode правильнее написал как посмотреть то  что вам нужно. Вам нужно посмотреть лог сервиса nginx.

Comment: В логах нет такого. Там mysql_1, pma_1 и php_1.

Comment: @Murphy `fastcgi_pass php:9000;` что здесь значит `php`? попробуйте так `fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;`

Comment: @tCode `php` означает имя сервиса, к которому будет стучаться nginx, при указании 127.0.0.1  `nginx` будет слать запросы сам на себя, где у него на порту 9000 ничего нет.

Comment: @zalex согласен, указал у себя в `hello-test.conf` название контейнера с php и у меня поднялся nginx и php: `fastcgi_pass php_1:9000;` имя контейнера с php в докере `php_1`, а бд не поднялась

Comment: @Murphy, укажите в `hello-test.conf`так: `fastcgi_pass <название контейнера с php>:9000;` и откройте http://localhost:8000/